# Cannot export component React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am new to React Native and trying to implement some of my knowledge from React like in this case: the function component. However, after I changed the layout a bit it shows an error in how I didn't export the component. Here's the error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of 'App'.
```

Here's a snapshot of the component:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Card,
    Background,
    Logo,
    Header,
    Title,
    Button,
    Divider,
} from "react-native";
import AudioRecorderPlayer, {
    AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType,
    AVEncodingOption,
    AudioEncoderAndroidType,
    AudioSet,
    AudioSourceAndroidType,
} from "react-native-audio-recorder-player";

const App = () => {
    const [initialtime, setInitialTime] = useState({
        isLoggingIn: false,
        recordSecs: 0,
        recordTime: "00:00:00",
        currentPositionSec: 0,
        currentDurationSec: 0,
        playTime: "00:00:00",
        duration: "00:00:00",
    });
    const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
    audioRecorderPlayer.setSubscriptionDuration(0.09);
    return (
        <Card
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                alignContent: "center",
                alignSelf: "center",
            }}
        >
            <Background>
                <Logo />
                <Header>InstaPlayer</Header>
                <Title>{initialtime[2]}</Title>
            </Background>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The file which import the App.js is AppEntry.js within node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js has the following content:

```
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../src/App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Does anyone have an answer to this or had a similar case? Any information would help. Thank you

Comment: How are you importing it? {App} or App

Comment: Need to look at your `import...` since it says check render method of 'App'.

Comment: I just updated it. I thought as it's the root element so it won't affect much

Comment: `react-native` does not seem to  have these components `Card` `Background` `Logo`...

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I was following this tutorial for a recording app: https://hackernoon.com/recording-audio-in-react-native-ca1d3uc8. It's kinda odd

Answer (score 0):

Try this version

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Card,
    Background,
    Logo,
    Header,
    Title,
    Button,
    Divider,
} from "react-native";
import AudioRecorderPlayer, {
    AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType,
    AVEncodingOption,
    AudioEncoderAndroidType,
    AudioSet,
    AudioSourceAndroidType,
} from "react-native-audio-recorder-player";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const [initialtime, setInitialTime] = useState({
        isLoggingIn: false,
        recordSecs: 0,
        recordTime: "00:00:00",
        currentPositionSec: 0,
        currentDurationSec: 0,
        playTime: "00:00:00",
        duration: "00:00:00",
    });
    const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
    audioRecorderPlayer.setSubscriptionDuration(0.09);

    return (
      <Card
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                alignContent: "center",
                alignSelf: "center",
            }}
        >
            <Background>
                <Logo />
                <Header>InstaPlayer</Header>
                <Title>{initialtime[2]}</Title>
            </Background>
        </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I just tried your method and fixed the hook to use the initial constructor method and it still shows the same error. I suspect that there's some problem with the jsx as if I changed jsx statement to the original when the project is populated, it works as normal

Comment: ```
export default function App() {
 const [initialtime, setInitialTime] = useState({
  isLoggingIn: false,
  recordSecs: 0,
  recordTime: "00:00:00",
  currentPositionSec: 0,
  currentDurationSec: 0,
  playTime: "00:00:00",
  duration: "00:00:00",
 });
 const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
 audioRecorderPlayer.setSubscriptionDuration(0.09);
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
   <StatusBar style="auto" />
  </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add the code for the file which is trying to import the App() file

Comment: ok try this - AppRegistry.registerComponent('App Name', () => App);

Comment: have you tried to restart your emulator? I think in general not all code changes update automatically sometimes you need to restart the emulator.

Comment: Yes, I did. I need to restart the expo every time I fix any errors

Comment: Ok sure, in that case i would say try to start again and start with the most basic version of expo example code possible and see if it works - https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/

Answer (score 0):

This is what my code looks like for the first file.

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App Name', () => App);
```

Comment: It's the same as mine. The registerRootComponent has the following codes:
```
import 'expo/build/Expo.fx';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
export default function registerRootComponent(App) {
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
}
//# sourceMappingURL=registerRootComponent.js.map
```

Comment: I even tried to use your part of the code but it still resulted in the same error